# How can I do sum two time values in javascript

Tags: javascript

I've been trying to implement the function that sums two values as hours. 
"Example: 01:30 + 00:30 = 02:00"

So I have this function below that works only if the sum of the two values is equal to a round number such as the example above. But the problem is when the values are say 01:45 + 00:20 it gives me 33:05 instead of 02:05.

I've tried several combinations but nothing has worked so far.

```
function sumOFHoursWorked(){
    var time1 = "00:45";
    var time2 = "01:20";


    var hour=0;
    var minute=0;
    var second=0;

    var splitTime1= time1.split(':');
    var splitTime2= time2.split(':');


    hour = parseInt(splitTime1[0])+parseInt(splitTime2[0]);
    minute = parseInt(splitTime1[1])+parseInt(splitTime2[1]);
    hour = hour + minute/60;
    minute = minute%60;
    second = parseInt(splitTime1[2])+parseInt(splitTime2[2]);
    minute = minute + second/60;
    second = second%60;

    var REalhourstime = ('0'  + hour).slice(-2)+':'+('0' + minute).slice(-2);
   alert(REalhourstime);
   document.getElementById('realhorasTB').innerHTML = REalhourstime;

      }
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not using Javascript's inbuild  datetime functions?

Comment: Using JavaScript's builtin Date object will make this smoother. `let date = new Date()` then `date.toLocaleTimeString` to get the format in hours:minutes.

Answer (score 2):

It actually depends on how your time will be, i mean it will be in `mm:ss` formet or `hh:mm:ss` or maybe `hh:mm:ss:msms` but for just simple second and minutes you can do something like this

```js
function sumOFHoursWorked(){
    var time1 = "00:45".split(':');
    var time2 = "01:20".split(':');
    
    let secondSum = Number(time1[1]) + Number(time2[1]);
    let minSum = Number(time1[0]) + Number(time2[0]);
    
    if(secondSum > 59){
      secondSum = Math.abs(60 - secondSum);
      minSum += 1;
    }
    
    if(secondSum < 10){
      secondSum = `0${secondSum}`;
    }
    
    if(minSum < 10){
      minSum = `0${minSum}`;
    }
    
    return `${minSum}:${secondSum}`;   
}


console.log(sumOFHoursWorked());
```

Comment: this seams to work for me. I'll be using this for now in less someone advises me otherwise. Thank you and thanks to every one else that tried to help me.

Answer (score 1):

I would convert it to minutes and subtract and then calculate hours and minutes.

```js
function totalMinutes (time) {
  var parts = time.split(":")
  return +parts[0] * 60 + +parts[1] 
}

function timeDiff (time1, time2) {
  var mins1 = totalMinutes(time1)
  var mins2 = totalMinutes(time2)
  var diff = mins2 - mins1
  var hours = '0' + (Math.floor(diff/60))
  var minutes = '0' + (diff - hours * 60)
  return (hours.slice(-2) + ':' + minutes.slice(-2))
}

console.log(timeDiff("00:45", "01:20"))
```

It will fail for times that go over midnight, a simple less than check can fix that.

```js
function totalMinutes (time) {
  var parts = time.split(":")
  return +parts[0] * 60 + +parts[1] 
}
function timeDiff (time1, time2) {
  var mins1 = totalMinutes(time1)
  var mins2 = totalMinutes(time2)

  if (mins2 < mins1) {
    mins2 += 1440
  }
  var diff = mins2 - mins1
  var hours = '0' + (Math.floor(diff/60))
  var minutes = '0' + (diff - hours * 60)
  return (hours.slice(-2) + ':' + minutes.slice(-2))
}

console.log(timeDiff("23:45", "00:45"))
```

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all, the `time1` and `time2` strings are missing the seconds at the end. For example, `var time1 = "00:45:00"`. Otherwise, your calculation will have some `NaN` values.
2. The main issue is that `hour` is a floating point number (~ 2.083333333333333), so `('0' + hour)` is '02.083333333333333'.

You could use something like this instead: `('0' + Math.floor(hour))`.

Comment: Ok so i'll add the missing seconds this indeed could be my problem.